# Got server error trying to display image with Yii

Tags: php, image, yii, frameworks

I have a problem that I can't get displayed picture with yii. Add 'enctype' form, but that doesn't helped.
This is in view:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'activity_form', 
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true, 
    'stateful'=>true, 
    'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')
  )); ?>

        <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pic'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'pic'); ?>  
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'pic'); ?>
    </div>
```

I got this error 
[image: Yii server error]

Here I want to get picture displayed

```
     <?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/protected/prod_pictures/'.$model->pic,"pics",array("width"=>200)); ?>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

I would like to have this picture visible alredy before the form is submitted (now I need to reload page), but I will try to solve it after this problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder in which you are storing images should be outside the protected folder and not in it. The protected folder is named as such since one cannot directly access its contents through a webserver by default.

Comment: It worked! thanks! :))

Maybe it's a easy thing to show image right after it's loaded? I know, it's ajax, but I'm really new in Yii things.